# Disabling days of week on Visual Form Builder Pro (jQuery DatePicker)

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui-datepicker, builder

I want to disable Monday & Tuesdays from the Date Picker – I found code to disable one day in my-js.js file and it works fine, I cannot get a second day to work – the following is my code that works for one day only – any help to add Tuesday would be great:
I have disabled the Mondays, also every day before today with this my-js.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        minDate:+1,
        beforeShowDay: disableMonday
    });
});

function disableMonday(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1), ''];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    minDate:+1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      if(date.getDay() === 1 || date.getDay() === 2){
        // must return array
        // first is a boolean (true or false)
        // second is a class 
        // third is a tooltip
         return [false];
      }else{
         return [true];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

DEMO: 
http://jsbin.com/uvexuk/4/edit

Links:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay